# Change Dart/Flutter formatting in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, formatting

is there a way to customize the dart/flutter formatter for VSCode?

The new way of formatting is terribly unreadable!

[image: Terrible]

How am i supposed to find brackets if they don't respect the indentation level?

I would like to have something like this:

[image: Ordered]

As you can see here you can follow the column to find where the closure ends.

I wonder if there is a way to customize the dart formatting.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add comma `,` between `)` whenever possible. If you are having problem with max line change the setting from

[image]

Comment: Ok, the "comma" trick worked perfectly. I already have 80, i increased to 300 to get what i wanted (still need to tweak maybe). I just need to remember the last comma everytime. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm begining with flutter and had the same issue with code formatting, the adding comma trick did the job for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is probably caused by a low value on the **Dart: Line Length** setting.

To fix this, try in Visual Studio Code going on:

- *File > Preferences > Settings* (or `CTRL + ,`).
- Search for "Dart Line Length" and edit the value (mine is set to 80, higher means more space horizontally).
- Save a .dart file and it should automatically re-indent/format your code.

[image: screenshot]